# What version of Hdf5 is used in ILNumerics?

Tags: hdf5, ilnumerics

I am building some evaluations with the trial version of ILNumerics and I would like to know which Hdf5 library version is deployed with ILNumerics for Windows. VisualStudio intellisense isn't helping me find a library version method or property. Given that the third party attribution page for ILNumerics cites The Hdf Group copyright through 2014, I surmise the version to be 1.8.13, compiled for 32-bit X86, but I would like confirmation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to write a program to query it? As HDF5 has the following [function](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/RM_H5.html#Library-Version):

```
herr_t H5get_libversion(unsigned *majnum, unsigned *minnum, unsigned *relnum)
```

Which returns the major, minor and release numbers.

Answer (score 1):

It is 1.8.9 (as of today). You can find out with the Layer_I namespace. All(?) official HDF5 API functions live here:

```
uint maj = 0, min = 0, rel = 0; 
ILNumerics.IO.HDF5.Layer_I.H5.H5get_libversion(ref maj, ref min, ref rel);
```

> 1.8.9

Comment: Thanks! The "Layer_I" namespace was the bit of information I was missing. Did I miss that in the documentation or is it undocumented?

Comment: All classes exposed in the Layer_I namespace are the result of an semi-automatic conversion from the C definitions provided by HDF Group. We use some of them for the higher level features and still expose the others which are not needed by ILNumerics. We did not document them because there are no tests for the signatures to be 100% correct. So if you need one of them and find an invalid signature please let us know: http://ilnumerics.net/mantis

Comment: BTW: the SO way of saying thanks is upvoting and marking as answer ;)